# Goals in Bing Ads are not exactly sourced from running Bing Ads? Could it be from running Google Ads?

Tags: google-analytics, google-adsense, bing, cpc-ads

I have been running Google ads for a few months now where I track the conversion goals using tags.

Now, I'm experimenting with Bing Ads and I have enabled tagging + conversion goals.

I have got a conversion goal on Bing Ads which has been recorded in Google Analytics too. How to know if I got this goal only through Bing Ads and not through Google Ads?

Answer (score 1):

Let's assume you have 10 conversions recorded in Bing interface.

On Google Analytics, if you scroll down the Conversions > Goals > Overview screen, at the bottom right you should be able to see the source/medium report. By default, analytics uses last-click attribution model. Now, if you have 10 conversions tracked corresponding to the source Bing, then you can be sure that every user arrived from Bing has converted.

In case, you have lesser than 10, say 9 conversions shown on analytics, that could mean this: An user who previously had visited via Bing, has once again arrived through some other source (and converted). Thus Analytics would have attributed that conversion to the latest source.

Answer (score 0):

Google analytics is not the same thing as Google Ads. Google Analytics is tracking and recording all traffic and all sources of traffic to your site (or should be if you've set it up correctly), so your Bing Ads traffic and conversions SHOULD be reported in Google Analytics  - something would be wrong if it wasn't.